# Distribute unsigned app iPhone

Tags: iphone, security, jailbreak

Is there any way to distribute an unsigned app through emails or internet?
I.e. `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=URL_TO_PLIST`.

Moreover, it is a security issue if it is possible to install unsigned app on a jailbroken device?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to distribute it, easiest to send is probably the `ipa` file.

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite understand what you're trying to do here - if you're trying to install an app that is not on the App Store and also unsigned with the `itms-services`-protocol, you are out of luck, as that is strictly for iTunes and App Store-links.

The only way to distribute an app that is not on the App Store, is with the `ipa`-file, but that has to be signed as well (at least for unjailbroken devices).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about jailbroken devices? how can you distribute .ipa to the device with out cable or cydia?

Comment: I don't think you can, Cydia is there for a reason, you always need Cydia to unpack and place the files where they belong.

Comment: OK, so my question is how jailbreakme.com installs Cydia? The installation looks like a distribution-protocol (with progress), and finishes successfully.

Comment: That is a really, really complicated process, but if you are experienced with Javascript, you could take a look at the source code and javascript-files of it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. But I still have a problem, I have a itms-services link with my app and I manage to install my app only when the provisioning profile is also installed on the device. Moreover, I have also one jailbroken device and I want to see whether I can install my app with no signature on that device.

Comment: I'm not too experienced with that, but I thing you need a signature for the app to run at all - as long as it is built with Xcode, you need the 'signature', as it works as a key.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in cydia with link like `cydia://package/[package name]`
However security is really a question here. Not sure if there any code review for the accepted packages.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I won't have cydia?

Comment: If there is no cydia on your device its probably not jailbroken. Although there are some alternatives, cydia is installed automagically right after jb and afaik most widely accepted package manager.

Comment: Lets say I want to install my app on a jailbroken device with no Cydia  (on purpose!). How can I distribute it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is an extremely late response, but the question isn't closed yet, so I'm assuming you still need an answer. It is a security concern, but with a jailbreak, users are technically "opening" their device to such security threats, so I don't think that's much of a concern. If they jailbreak, they probably know what they're doing.

To answer the first part of your question, you can use ldid to pseudo-sign the app and then create an itms-services:// link that users tap to install. The only caveat to this option is that the iOS Device will contact oscp.apple.com & ax.init.itunes.apple.com to verify the app's signature. If you want to bypass this, you'll have to change the DNS settings of the iOS device using a mobile configuration file. Do this using Apple's iPhone Configuration Utility, which will generate a .mobileconfig with your specified settings. You won't have to generate a specific file for each device, so you can make one and you're done.

Anyways, back to the topic, jailbreaking doesn't remove the need for codesigning, it only removes the need for an app to be signed with Apple's certificate(s). itms-services:// is a bypass (for developers) of the same "need". Since Apple obviously doesn't want people who aren't developers just signing apps that aren't approved by Apple and installing them, they've implemented certificate checks. The signing-certificate is cross-checked with Apple's two servers. One of the servers (I don't know which) checks for "iPhone Developer:" in the name of the certificate. The other checks that it was signed by Apple's WWDRCA Certificate. If the iOS Device gets a response from either of the servers signifying that the app is "bad". If the iOS Device doesn't get a response, it will still install the app.

The way to go with this in order to bypass would be to clone a DNS server, and create a specific entry that will change the IP of these two servers to something (anything) else. That way, the Device will not get a response, and will install the application.

Comment: also, both versions of jailbreakme.com are PDF exploits, meaning that they take advantage of a glitch in the CoreImage Library, so they don't use itms-services:// links. It may seem like they do, mainly because you can see the "loading" bar moving to the right, but I'm pretty sure this was just a nifty trick C0mex programmed into the code for both, to let users know that Cydia was actually downloading, and make it seem smooth and not have Cydia randomly just pop into the screen. I think you would know how panicked users would be if they knew something was installing, but didn't know what.

Answer (score 0):

1. modify the file **SDKSettings.plist** ： make code sign required value is NO
2. when build, selected project (not target) -- build setting --  code signning identity: Dont code sign
3. build, get the **.ipa** file  can run on the jailbreak device