# Can build iOS app via XCode without Apple Developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to build some iOS apps (on XCode) but will not submit them on the Apple App Store. I will submit them on some another mobile store like Cydia. May I build apps in Xcode without an Apple Developer account (no provisioning, no certification,...) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can. You only need developer account to deploy to App Store and run on a device that isn't jail broken.

Comment: Without a developer account may I have some problem when build app on XCode ? (I am talking about SignCode in building process, build to .ipa include).

Comment: The app is signed with your certificate and provisioning profile that you purchase so it can run on nonjailbroken devices. I could be wrong but on a jailbroken device, you should be able to install anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654565/distribute-unsigned-app-iphone

Comment: More question :) I have build an app with XCode patched by JailCoder. Now I have a .ipa file. Can that file be submit on other mobile store for download and use without problem ?