# Deploy/testing Apache Cordova apps to ios devices without Mac

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have an ipad Mini 2 and I need to test my JavaScript Cordova applications in it. So far, I can only run in a simulator.

I don't have a Mac nor an Apple developer account. I don't want to publish my app.

Is it possible to deploy to my physical ios device without Mac, similar to USB Debugging with Android devices?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630309/deploying-apache-cordova-app-to-ipad-without-apple-developer-account)

Comment: @Lioman nope. This OP is apple-free in development but has a device. ie has no access to Xcode. That other question was related to being able to deploy/test without having an apple developper account BUT with some Apple machine and device at hand.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg sorry, I have misread this.

Comment: You can use phonegap build, but you still need an apple developer account

Comment: You could install a cracked mac (Hackintosh) on your system to use XCode. But you will still need a developer account to deploy a build to your iPad.

Comment: Well, if hou have a Hackintosh, read the answer in @Lioman ' s quoted SO question. Apparently you could deploy without an dev appleId.

Comment: Do I need to pay for an Apple dev account in order to test my app with Hackintosh?