# Build and run iOS app using Apache Cordova on VS 2015 without Mac

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova

I have Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2015 Community version and created one "hello world" using Apache Cordova.

I want to build and run that app without using Mac pc remotely.

I have my iphone 6 but don't know how to run that app in my phone like run apk in android.

I have my developer account but don't have Mac system so Is it possible to run and get the ".ipa" file from windows and run in my phone by debugging or release it, any tutorial any help would be appreciate.

I have come across these links but every link suggest to have Mac Mini / Mac to build the app, even on a Microsoft's official site in Link 4 they say it is not possible but still is there any way to do it please suggest me thanks in advance.

[Link 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/06/05/developing-for-ios-using-the-tools-for-apache-cordova.aspx)

[Link 2](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jan/06/Using-Cordova-and-Visual-Studio-to-build-iOS-Mobile-%20%20Apps#iOSsupportisExcellent)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582781/deploy-testing-apache-cordova-apps-to-ios-devices-without-mac)

[Link 4](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#ios)

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: Ohhh sad to know still thanks for reply @Joerg.

Comment: you can use an online service to build the app (like phonegap build), or rent an online mac (mac in cloud)

Comment: @jcesarmobile as you suggested I have used phonegap build but it requires the p12 certificate and provisioning profile, I have developer ID but how to get p 12 certificate and provosioning profile! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can generate the .p12 file from windows using OpenSSL, google for tutorials.