# Do I need a developer account to run iOS simulator with Visual Studio Cordova?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-ios

I have a Windows 10 PC running Visual Studio 2015 and a MacBook Pro Yosemite running Xcode 7.2. I am trying to test my Cordova app on the Macbook using Debug->->iOS->Remote Device in Visual Studio. I have properly configured the connection and it begins the build properly but it fails at "No provisioning profile found". Sure enough if I go into XCode->Preferences->Accounts there are no provisioning profiles. When I try to create one it directs me to purchase a developer account.

Is it possible to debug to remote device (agent) without purchasing an Apple Developer Account? I currently have their Free developer option. If not, any ideas on how to resolve a provisioning profile issue? I have seen this post:

[Deploying Apache Cordova App to iPad Without Apple Developer Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630309/deploying-apache-cordova-app-to-ipad-without-apple-developer-account)

but unfortunately this isn't exactly my issue, I can't even build properly for testing only yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can debug on a remote device without having to purchase an Apple Developer Account by using XCode 7 and your free Apple ID. You can find the steps in this topic - [Setup guide: Target iOS mobile devices in a Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova project](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/).
Scroll down to the section named "Option 2: Use your free Apple ID".